# Unable to properly swap data rows from one table to another in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have taken a sample data table using angular material with some data rows. I have also added an empty data table where  I am transferring rows from first table to empty table.

I am able to properly move rows from first table into my second table. But when I am making a selectAll action , the rows are not getting selected.

But when I am trying to select one row at a time and clicking on **Move to First Table Button** , the row is getting deleted instead on getting transferred to first table.

Please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-r4s19h?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I just missed to make the selection for checkedDatasource...

Replace the code with this for All Rows Selection..

```
  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  masterCheckedToggle() {
    this.isAllCheckedSelected()?
      this.checkedSelection.clear() : 
      this.checkedDataSource.data.forEach(row => this.checkedSelection.select(row));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the below code , It will remove the record from your first collection.

```
this.uncheckedData.splice(index, 1);
```

If you wan't to know the selected rows in later point , I would suggest set a IsSelected property

```
    this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
          let index: number = this.uncheckedData.findIndex(d => d === item);
if(index){
          this.uncheckedData[index].IsSelected= true;
          this.checkedData.push(this.uncheckedData[index]);
          // this.uncheckedData.splice(index, 1);
}

        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.... but I am not getting what exactly I am trying to do...

Comment: actually after transferring rows to second table ,I am able to select one each at a time and send back again to first table but I am unable to selectAll operation in my second table

Comment: @Heena Also I would suggest , you can manage two grids with one datasource also by adding some property and apply filter on based on that property. You don't need to keep checked data and unchecked data

Comment: @Heena are you deleting the rows you have selected from the first table when moving ? if you are doing here is a better solution by updating your code with one collection. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-uejvnm?file=app/table.component.ts

Comment: @Heena check this , you will get an idea how you can manage with one datasource

Comment: But in the stackblitz above for which you have provided the link there is no difference i found ....?

Comment: yes its better version than mine earlier... thanks for your help